# Jest testing of hook onClick calls

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-hooks

This error appears when running this onClick call test with Jest, does anyone know why?
I'm developing an app with React, and I'm new to its testing framework. I'm trying to develop a testing method to check if an onClick button is clicked. I've read that I need a "spy" function to get the information about whether or not it's been called.

The preference is to keep an enzyme and jest test stack.

```
    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: 1
    Received: 0

      46 |       test("onClick calls props.onClick", () => {
      47 |           nodes.simulate("click");
    > 48 |           expect(onClickMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
```

Since I'm mocking onClick in a way that was to return the value 1
Test

```
import React from "react";

import Enzyme, { shallow } from "enzyme";
import Adapter from "@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17";
import { expect } from "@jest/globals";
import { findByTestId } from "../../utils/test";

import Accordion from "./accordion.jsx";

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });

const defaultProps = {
  opened: {},
  Accordion: {},
};

const setup = (props = {}) =>
  shallow(<Accordion {...props} {...defaultProps} />).dive();

describe("Function calls", () => {
  let wrapper, nodes, props;

  
  describe("Button", () => {
      let onClickMock;
      beforeEach(() => {
          onClickMock = jest.fn();
          props = {onClick: onClickMock};
          wrapper = setup(props);
          nodes = findByTestId(wrapper, "arrow");
      });
      test("onClick calls props.onClick", () => {
          nodes.simulate("click");
          expect(onClickMock.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
      });
  });
});
```

Component

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

import { IoIosArrowForward, IoIosArrowDown } from 'react-icons/io';

import styles from '../../variables';

const Accordion = (props) => {
  const [opened, setOpened] = useState(false);

  const renderArrow = () => {
    if (!opened) return <IoIosArrowForward className="is-size-4" color={styles.primaryBlue} />
    return <IoIosArrowDown className="is-size-4" color={styles.primaryBlue} />
  }

  const renderPanel = () => {
    if (opened) return <Panel>{props.children}</Panel>
  }

  const togglePanel = () => {
    setOpened(!opened)
  }

    return (
      <AccordionTile data-testid="accordionTile" className={props.className + " px-6 py-5 is-clickable"}>
             <p data-testid="arrow" onClick={togglePanel} className="is-flex is-flex-direction-row is-align-items-flex-start is-justify-content-flex-start is-size-5">
          {renderArrow()} &nbsp; {props.title}
        </p>
        {renderPanel()}
      </AccordionTile>

    );
  }

  export default Accordion
```

Could someone guide me to finish testing this onClick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you click and check that content appears:

```
wrapper = setup({
  children: <span id="test" />
});
// accordion is collapsed yet
expect(wrapper.find('span#test')).toHaveLength(0); 
nodes.simulate('click');
// accordion is expanded; children nodes are rendered
expect(wrapper.find('span#test')).toHaveLength(1);
```

Also you better switch from `shallow()` to `mount()` *before* you run into [issues with `useEffect` is not called](https://github.com/enzymejs/enzyme/issues/2086). You will still be able to avoid rendering some nested components by explicitly mocking them:

```
jest.mock('react-icons/io', () => ({
 IoIosArrowForward: (props) => <span {...props} />,
 IoIosArrowDown: props => <span {...props} /> 
}));
```

And also in way you do it now:

```
<Accordion {...props} {...defaultProps} />
```

your `defaultProps` overwrite `props` with the same name. To have it working in reasonable way(when `defaultProps` can be overwritten by `props` if you want to) it should go in reverse order:

```
<Accordion  {...defaultProps} {...props} />
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the touches, I've already done some optimizations, but the error now is `` `
    The “simulate” method must be run on 1 node. 0 found instead.
`` `

Comment: So render does not give an arrow button you need to click. Call `console.log(wrapper.debug())` and check what's rendered and what's wrong with arrow button

Comment: I completed the test with " describe("Function calls arrow", () => {
  let wrapper, nodes, props;
  describe("Arrow", () => {
      let onClickMock;

      beforeEach(() => {
          onClickMock = jest.fn();
          wrapper = setup(props);
          nodes = findByTestId(wrapper, "arrow");
      });

      test("onClick calls props.onClick arrow", () => {
          nodes.simulate("click", { target: { value: onClickMock(true) } });
          expect(onClickMock).toBeCalled();
      });
  });
});"